# Mysql select distinct if column equal to otherwise dont select

Tags: mysql, select, distinct

I have a table like this:

```
   id | id_user | approved 
   -----------------
   1  | 15      | 1
   2  | 11      | 1
   3  | 15      | 1
   4  | 11      | -1
   5  | 6       | 1
```

I want to select distict values of id_user only if every approved of each id_users is equal to 1.
Output:

```
   id | id_user | approved 
   -----------------
   1  | 15      | 1
   2  | 6       | 1
```

As you can see, id_user 11 is not selected because one approved value is equal to -1. How can i do this in mysql ?

I've tried `SELECT * FROM table WHERE approved != -1 GROUP BY id_user` but obviously it does not work so i've decided to ask here this question.

Thank you very much for your time.

//Later edit

I have one more question. I have to modify the query. I have one more table
`validation`

```
id | id_user | valid
--------------------
1  | 15      | 1
```

which i have to join with the other table, but with a condition. For example, let's say that your query outputs(correctly):

```
id | id_user | approved 
-----------------
1  | 15      | 1
2  | 6       | 1
```

What i want is to join those 2 tables:

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT va.id_user,va.valid FROM validation va WHERE va.valid != 1) t2 
ON t2.id_user = t1.id_user
```

but select only those rows for which valid is NOT equal to 1. It's very possible that `id_user` from the first table might not exist in the `validation` table. In this case, the query should return exactly what Alex's query outputs.

Let me give you an example. First table is the same:

```
 id | id_user | approved 
 -----------------
 1  | 15      | 1
 2  | 11      | 1
 3  | 15      | 1
 4  | 11      | -1
 5  | 6       | 1
 6  | 6       | 1
```

`validation` table:

```
 id | id_user | valid
 --------------------
 1  | 15      | 1
```

The query should output:

```
 id | id_user 
 ------------
 1  | 6
```

id_user = 15 is in second table with `valid=1`, so it won't be selected

id_user = 11 has a -1 value in approved field, so it won't be selected

id_user = 6 has 1 in both approved fields, but is not present in second table, i want it to be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/607e16/2

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
GROUP BY id_user
HAVING COUNT(*)=SUM(approved)
```

it doesn't return exact resultset as you described. But in fact you need just

```
SELECT id_user
FROM t1
GROUP BY id_user
HAVING COUNT(*)=SUM(approved)
```

because htereis no rule and it doesn't matter which `id` or `approved` is returned.

Keep in mind this solution works only if `approved` can be just `1, 0, -1` if value could be `2,3,4,... etc` this solution will not work.

**UPDATE** According to your 2nd question you can join `validation` table this way:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96b4b/1

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN validation v
ON v.id_user = t1.id_user
GROUP BY t1.id_user
HAVING COUNT(*)=SUM(approved)
  AND SUM(v.valid) IS NULL
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. And yes, in my table, approved can be just `1,0,-1`. Thank you very much, Sir. I will accept your answer as soon as i can.

Comment: Alex, i would be grateful if you could review the changes i've made. Thank you again.